# How to get a global reference of an array without knowing its size beforehand?

Tags: java, arrays, global-variables, global

I'm stuck in a situation, where I need a global reference of an array but I get to know it's size only after the user enters it.

I've tried to make another class and do something, but still the problem remains the same, I can only declare  local array since I don't have it's size beforehand.

What can be done?

Comment: Use List instead of Array as your problem already solved in the implementation of  `List`

Comment: Obviously I can do that, but can something be done using arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Provider that holds the array and gives Access to it via a static getter-method. Like so:

```
public class MyGLobalArrayProvider {
    private static String[] myGlobalArray;

    public static String[] getGlobalArray() {
        return myGlobalArray;
    }


    public static void doSomeUpdateMagic() {…}
}
```

Generally I would prefere a solution using Dependency Injection with Guice or Spring. In that case you would inject a singleton Service that holds the array. This would decouple your Code which is not only usefull for testing but also leads to better maintainabilty.

Another classic approach would be the Singleton-Pattern if the DI-Approach is inappropriate heavy.